# Alexandroff one-point compactification = Freudenthal end point compactification / set of ends

Tags: general-topology, compactness

By *spaces* I mean locally compact, $\sigma$-compact, connected, locally connected, Hausdorff topological spaces.

I need a **reference** (**not** a proof, I already have one -- or at least I think so; counterexamples are welcome) for the following fact. I believe it should be standard.

> If $X$ is a non-compact space, then the Alexandroff one-point
>   compactification of $X$ is homeomorphic to the quotient space
>   $\mathfrak{F}X\big/\mathcal{E}(X)$, where $\mathfrak{F}X$ is the
>   Freudenthal compactification of $X$ and $\mathcal{E}(X)$ is the set of
>   ends of $X$.

Definitions of both $\mathfrak{F}X$ and $\mathcal{E}(X)$ are recalled below.

---

Recall that an *[end](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End_%28topology%29)* of a topological space $X$ is a function $$\varepsilon: \{K\subseteq X: K \text{ is compact }\} \to 2^X\smallsetminus\{\emptyset\}$$ 
such that $\varepsilon(K)$ is an unbounded (= of non-compact closure) connected component of $X\smallsetminus K$ and $\varepsilon(L)\subseteq \varepsilon(K)$ for all compact sets $K\subseteq L \subseteq X$. The set of ends of $X$ is denoted by $\mathcal{E}(X)$.

For $\varepsilon \in \mathcal{E}(X)$ and a compact set $K\subseteq X$ define $$N(\varepsilon,K)=(X\smallsetminus K) \cup \bigl\{\delta\in\mathcal{E}(X):\delta(K)=\varepsilon(K)\bigr\}.$$

Let $\mathfrak{F}X=X\cup \mathcal{E}(X)$ with topology given by the following [bases of open neighbourhoods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neighbourhood_system): for a basis of neighbourhoods of $x\in X$ we take a basis of neighbourhoods of $x$ in $X$; for $\varepsilon\in\mathcal{E}(X)$ the basis of neighbourhoods is $$\{N(\varepsilon,K):K\subseteq X \text{ is compact }\}.$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing special about the Freudenthal compactification in this respect.
This holds for any (Hausdorff) compactification of any non-compact locally compact
Hausdorff space. As a reference you might use Engelking's *General Topology*,
Theorem 3.5.11.

> THE ALEXANDROFF COMPACTIFICATION THEOREM. Every non-compact locally compact
>   space X has a compactification $\omega X$ with one-point remainder. **This
>   compactification is the smallest element in $C(X)$ with respect to the order
>   $\le$**, its weight is equal to the weight of the space X.

$C(X)$ refers to the collection of equivalence classes of compactifications of
$X$ and $\le$ is defined by

> Let $c_2X \le c_1X$ if there exists a continuous mapping $f: c_1X \to c_2X$
>   such that $fc_1 = c_2$;

Note that any such $f$ is a quotient map.